# Datatable td not align with each other

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

Please see below image for the output, any help will be much appreciated. Already trying to figure out for the whole week.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKKvD.png)

> ```
> <table class="table table-hover" id="tblCarlisting" style="width:100%" aria-hidden="true">                                                                
>      <tbody align="left"></tbody>
> </table>
>
> <script src="~/Scripts/datatables.min.js"></script> 
> <script type="text/javascript">
> function initialize() {
>             }
>             $.extend(initialize.prototype, {
>                 populateDataTable: function (data) {
>                     if (data != null) {
>                         var dtTable = $("#tblCarlisting").DataTable({
>                             "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
>                                 /* You can simply apply bold here without conditioning */
>                                 if (iDisplayIndex == 0) {
>                                     $('td', nRow).each(function () {
>                                         $(this).html('<div class="boldText">' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
>                                     });
>                                 }
>                                 return nRow;
>                             },
>                             data: data,
>                             orderCellsTop: true,
>                             fixedHeader: {
>                                 header: true,
>                                 footer: true
>                             },
>                             scrollCollapse: true,
>                             scrollX: true,
>                             scrollY: false,
>                             searching: false,
>                             paging: false,
>                             info: false,
>                             ordering: false,
>                             columns: [
>                                 { data: "PLATE_NO" },
>                                 { data: "CAR_DESC" },
>                                 { data: "TRANSMISSION_N_GAS" },
>                                 { data: "STARTINGBID_AMOUNT" },
>                                 { data: "YEAR_MODEL" },
>                                 { data: "MILEAGE" },
>                                 { data: "WAREHOUSE" },
>                             ]                            
>                         });
>                     }
>                 }
>             });
> function loadCarlisting() {
>                 var u = $("#AuctionTypeId option:selected").val();
>                 var a = $("#item_BidOpeningStart option:selected").val();
>                 $.ajax({
>                     type: "POST",
>                     url: '/Home/LoadCarListing?AuctionTypeID=' + u + '&&bidschedid=' + a,
>                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>                     dataType: "json",
>                     success: function (data) {
>                         initialize.prototype.populateDataTable(data);
>                     },
>                     error: function (xhr, status, error) {
>
>                         alert('Error loading results.');
>                     }
>                 });
>             }
> </script>
> ```

Already tried different approach but I'd runout of solutions. It was the same scenario with the header, misalignment, so I remove the table header and make the first td to look as header.